# TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtypes'

Tags: python, pandas

I have just updated python to 3.10.3 and now it I am getting the above error.  If I remove the dtypes I can run the code.  Has something changed in the new version?  thanks

```
 new_df = pd.read_excel(data_path + '{} REPORT TRACKING - Master Copy.xlsx'.format(start_date),                                                                                                
                                            dtypes={
                                                    'col1': 'str',
                                                    'col2': 'str',
                                                    'col3': 'str',
                                                    'Date': 'object',
                                                  },
                                        sheet_name='Report Tracking',
                                        skiprows=[0],
                                        index_col=None,
                                )
```

Comment: `pandas.read_excel` takes a `dtype` argument, but no `dtypes` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Argument should be [`dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) (singular, not plural):

```py
 new_df = pd.read_excel(
     data_path + '{} REPORT TRACKING - Master Copy.xlsx'.format(start_date),                                                                                                
     dtype={
         'col1': 'str',
         'col2': 'str',
         'col3': 'str',
         'Date': 'object',
    },
    sheet_name='Report Tracking',
    skiprows=[0],
    index_col=None,
)
```

Comment: My bad, sorry about that.